# cURL when fetches a specific site, sends random characters (encrypted?)

Tags: curl

A very novice question, I'm sure, but I've been at it for days and found no answer. I recently installed cURL on Windows, along with the CA Certificates and everything. And it works beautifully. Except for this one site.

When I send the command `curl https://kat.cr` it fills it with what seems to be random characters which look as if it's all sent encrypted. I've even tried the verbose mode, and I don't see anything particularly different. I've tried saving it as an html document and, to no avail. The endless string of characters appears as is in the browser when I open the html file. I'm uploading the output in a text file, for anyone who's willing to help me sort it out. It does not happen on any other site. There, I get a perfectly readable html code. Here, I guess its about how the site is setup up or what. I just want to fetch its source code for a script that I'm creating.

Link to output of command: http://txt.do/57bkz

Comment: Have you changed the user agent string to that of a real browser?

Comment: Could you please provide more details on how? Like I said, a mere beginner... A specific command or arguments would be nice... Thanks

Comment: Hmm, don't bother... I googled it to figure it out and did try it... But the result is no different... Why is this happening?

Comment: Wow, thank you!! That worked perfectly... Such a simple solution! Can't thank you enough! Pretty negligent of me to not see that in the verbose mode. Do you mind adding a proper answer for future users?

Comment: That's the thing with duplicates. If the question is a duplicate and the answer in the linked question solved your problem, then there really is not need for another answer that simply duplicates the content. You can confirm the duplicate by clicking on the link above your question.